# Application hangs when Timer is turn off/on frequently

Tags: android, timer, camera

I have Multi-Shot facility in my camera application. I am using following short of code to do that.

```
if (TIMER_STARTED) {
    multishotTimer.cancel();
    multishotTimer.purge();
    multishotTimer = null;
    TIMER_STARTED = false;
} else {
    multishotTimer = new Timer();
    multishotTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TIMER_STARTED = true;
            Camera camera = surfaceView.getCamera();
            camera.takePicture(null, null,
                    new HandlePictureStorage());
        }
    }, 1000, 5000L);
}
```

Here, **TIMER_STARTED** is boolean flag which indicate whether timer is started or not. **HandlePictureStorage** is class which handles **PictureCallback**.

**Question:**
When first time i click on "MultiShot" button, it will start timer and take picture every 5 seconds. To stop timer, I one more time click on same button. But if I continuously clicking on button, application hangs and force stopped. Then after I need to switch off my device due to camera is used by stopped service and can't release it lightly. How can I manage start and stop timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need TIMER_STARTED to choose whether the button will start or stop the multishot: you can simply check `if (multishotTimer != null)`.

But even after this fix, clicking too fast may be dangerous: you should not create a new Timer between `takePicture` and `HandlePictureStorage`.

```
private bool isCapturing = false;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (multishotTimer != null) {
        multishotTimer.cancel();
        multishotTimer.purge();
        multishotTimer = null;
    }
    else if (!isCaptureing) {
        multishotTimer = new Timer();
        multishotTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                isCapturing = true;
                Camera camera = surfaceView.getCamera();
                camera.takePicture(null, null,
                    new HandlePictureStorage());
            }
        }, 1000, 5000L);
    }
}

class HandlePictureStorage implements ... {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(...) {
        isCaptureing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i got a clue from your answer and fixed problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `TIMER_STARTED = true;` from the timer task to the `else` part, for example after scheduling the timer.

To improve the performance, you should create a `TimerTask` field instead of recreating an anonymous class every time you create and start the timer.

Comment: but if i move TIMER_STARTED to else part, it is disable for 5 secs and then for a while it is enable to "disable" multishot.